# Repeating entries in match in R

Tags: r, duplicates

In the following example, there is repeating entries in the second vector. How do I make R to tell me the position of both appearances of 5, please?

```
 match(5, c(1,2,9,5,3,6,7,4,5))
```

Comment: `which( duplicated(v) | duplicated(v, fromLast=T) )` is a more general solution, and will automatically detect and catch *all* duplicated values, not just a single specific value (e.g. 5)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `which` function:

```
which(c(1,2,9,5,3,6,7,4,5) == 5)
```